# Get Images from Photos in Iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to get images from gallery in iphone by name..
like if i have 10 photos in gallery one.png,two.png,three.png and so on.
and i want to use two.png. how can i get that image. and use it in my UIImageView.
Is this possible or not?

Comment: do you need only images or images+video

Comment: now i am unable to answer...:(

Answer (score 2):

`imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)`

in this method write

```
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
[ImageViewName setImage:image];
[picker1 dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: i dont want to use imagePicker.

Comment: @Zohaib it's your static image gallery which is created by you ?

Answer (score 1):

For picking image from photolibrary you can use [UIImagePickerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html).

If you have the assetlibrary url of the image then you can use the following code:

```
typedef void (^ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock)(ALAsset *asset);
typedef void (^ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock)(NSError *error);    

ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset)
{
    ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [myasset defaultRepresentation];
    CGImageRef iref = [myasset aspectRatioThumbnail];

    UIImage *images;
    if (iref) 
    {
        images = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref scale:[rep scale] orientation:(UIImageOrientation)[rep orientation]];
    }
    else
    {
        images = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Noimagey.png"];
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            yourImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            [yourImageView setImage:images];

            });
};

ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock  = ^(NSError *myerror)
{
    UIImage *images = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Nofile.png"];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [yourImageView setImage:images];

        });

};    

NSURL *asseturl = [NSURL URLWithString:yourAssetUrl];
ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[assetslibrary assetForURL:asseturl resultBlock:resultblock failureBlock:failureblock];
```

If you are using Assets library for picking image, always remember:

1. **It is an asynchronous process**
2. **Always bind image to imageView in main thread from asset block**

Comment: let say i have saved image with temp.png. now what will be the url of this to get image from assetlibrary?

Comment: that's an arbitary url like: assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=1000000003&ext=JPG

Comment: you cannot save image to photolibrary using names.

Comment: When i am saving image how will i know what id is generated for that image. and can i access that image with id?

Comment: @Zohaib: if you are using `- (void)writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:(CGImageRef)imageRef orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)orientation completionBlock:(ALAssetsLibraryWriteImageCompletionBlock)completionBlock` method then you will get the url from the completion block parameters.

Comment: @Zohaib: when you save the image change the completion block like: completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) and log the assetUrl.

Comment: Thanks. i will try this and will come back to you later